# Internet Explorer object in Excel VBA. IE.Document.all("Name"). value not work

Tags: excel, vba, object, internet-explorer

I use:

```
For Each ele In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")

  Debug.Print ele.Name; "-"; ele.Value

   Debug.Print IE.Document.all("peticion.numeroPeticion").Value

Next
```

the result of first debug is: peticion.numeroPeticion-X20292130
but next debug: run-time error 438;object doesn't support this property or method.

I tried read the value  of "peticion.numeroPeticion"

Comment: Not sure but `all` denotes collection so `Value` is incorrect. Try to print the value of the first element, `IE.Document.all("peticion.numeroPeticion")(0).Value`, but check if the first element index is 0 or 1.

Comment: thanks, thanks, Thank you very much
"peticion.numeroPeticion" is the name ,and exists 2 times in the webpage.
with IE.Document.all("peticion.numeroPeticion")(0).Value work correct!